# unable to add custom options with existing products in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am working on a magento site. I can't edit or add custom options of my existing products. No error message is showing, it's showing "product has been saved successfully"  But when I create a new product and try to add options to them, it's working fine also can edit options.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable developer mode from index.php and check it.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
 }
```

replace with

```
  Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

remove if condition only. And try to save product and check it what error display.